# Javac is making all names of my code into myclass.class

Tags: java

I was just trying to compile my java code then I did this in the cmd:

```
chdir C:\All_files (my directory)
javac Hello.java
```

then when I did this:

```
java Hello
오류: 기본 클래스 hello을(를) 찾거나 로드할 수 없습니다.
(Error: cannot find class hello)
```

then I did this:

```
javac myclass
```

then it worked.

How do I fix that?

Here is my code:

```
public class Hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Windows 10");
    }
}
```

I want to know how do I make javac produce the right title for the compiled class.

Comment: Can we see your Java class?

Comment: You'd better post your source code.

Comment: *Error: cannot find class hello* are you using lowercase within the class definition as `public class hello{` ?

Comment: *What* code? Your question is meaningless without including the code in it, or better still a minimal example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Does `Hello.java` have `public class myclass` in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to fix?

First you compiled your source file with `javac Hello.java`...

Then you tried to run it with `java Hello`...
However the command `java` requires a fully qualified class name. What you supplied (`Hello`) seems to me, like the name of he `.class` file, without extension.

When you tried with `java myclass`, it worked, because it is the fully qualified class name of your class...

See: [`java` and `javaw` reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)